# Finite locally groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Let be $V\leq \operatorname{Aut}\left( G\right),\ N\vartriangleleft G$ and $V$-invariant.
>   Consider the semidirect product of $V$ with $G$. Let $C_{G}(V)=\{g\in G:g^{v}=g\}$ and $[G,V]=\langle g^{-1}g^{v} : g\in G,v\in V\rangle $. For finite groups the following applies:
>
> If $(|V|,|G|)=1$, then
>
> 1. $C_{G/N}(V)=C_{G}(V)N/N$.
> 2. $G=[G,V]C_{G}(V)$.

The proof uses the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem and can be found in the book *An Introduction the Theory of Finite Groups*, Hans Kurzweil and Bernd Stellmacher, page 184.

I would like to show this for finite locally groups (this is, $\forall H\leq G$, $H$ finitely generated $\Rightarrow H$ finite) such that $(|V|,|g|)=1,\forall g\in G$.

For 2. I've got:

Let $a\in G $ and $H=\langle a^{V}\rangle =\langle a^{v};v\in V\rangle$. $H$ is finite, because $G$ is finite locally, is $V$-invariant and $(|V|,|H|)=1$. Then for $H$ we have, $H=[H,V]C_{H}(V)$. 
Then, $a\in [H,V]C_{H}(V)\leq [G,V]C_{G}(V)$ and so $G=[G,V]C_{G}(V)$ as required!

I would like to know the solution given for 1 it is correct.

Comment: You need to show that, for any $g \in G$ with $gN \in C_{G/N}(V)$, there exists $n \in N$ with $gn \in C_G(V)$. Just apply the finite group result to $H = \langle g^V \rangle$.

Comment: I think doesn't give right because $N$ need not be nornal in $H$ and $HN$ it is not finite.

Comment: But you can apply it with $H \cap N$ in place of $N$.

Comment: $gN \in C_{G/N}(V)\Rightarrow g^{v}N=gN,\forall v\in
V\Rightarrow gN\in C_{HN/N}(V)\cong C_{H/H\cap N}(V)=C_{H}(V)(H\cap
N)/(H\cap N)$ . Therefore, $gN=x(H\cap N)$ com $x\in C_{H}(V)\leq
C_{G}(V)$.Is complete?

Comment: What you call "finite locally" is usually called "locally finite".

Comment: User2040: yes, is true!